# Crear poligonos uno a uno

Tags: java

Existe alguna forma en la cual el JPanel (nombrado TestingPanelGraphics) vaya creando un dibujo con paintComponent poco a poco? Ocupo visualizar conforme se va creando, en este caso cada polígono. Sin embargo, todos aparecen de un solo, estoy utilizando NetBeans, agradezco sus aportes.

```
class TestingPanelGraphics extends javax.swing.JPanel {
    Polygon[] poly = new Polygon[10];
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){ //pintaComponentes
        super.paintComponent(g);
            for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
                g.drawPolygon(poly[i]); //poligonos que quiero que vayan apareciendo
            }
    }
}
```

Explicado con palabras textuales: Corro el programa y la ventana se abre. Tengo un JPanel y un botón. Al presionar dicho botón, el JPanel debe de empezar a mostrar figuras una a una. La cantidad de figuras que se necesitan se encuentra dentro de la misma función que las muestra. Para aclarar mejor la parte de aparición de las figuras podemos tomar como ejemplo: se presiona el botón -> necesito 3 rombos, a cada 5segs aparece uno más y todo termina cuando el tercero se muestra en pantalla

Comment: No queda claro el contexto en tu pregunta. ¿Qué acción habría que hacer para que se creen los elementos (pulsar algún botón, esperar X tiempo, etc)?

Comment: Hay un botón en mi JFrame que dice empezar

Comment: Entonces en lugar de lanzar una creación de 10 elementos (según se ve en el `for`) creas un solo elemento. Y cuando se le de de nuevo al botón creas otro elemento y así.

Comment: Lo que ocupo es que la función inicie hasta completar el total de elementos, pero realmente tengo muy poco conocimiento de si existe alguna forma de pausar del sistema de forma en la que a cada cierto tiempo se muestre algo, en este caso la figura. El botón de empezar solo se encarga de iniciar el ciclo.

Comment: En programación se puede hacer todo lo que uno desee o casi todo, pero siempre conviene organizar la lógica del código para poder lograr cada cosa de una manera óptima. Trata de explicar lo que quieres (por escrito) a ver si podemos ayudarte mejor, porque analizando el código no se logra entender el propósito. ¿Qué lógica sigues (presiono aquí y hace esto, presiono allí y hace lo otro), y qué quieres lograr (que se muestren X cosas de forma secuencial), y por qué quieres que sea así? etc. En este tipo de problemas y con ese código, sin el contexto es difícil entender lo que quieres.

Comment: Podemos explicar mi código de la siguiente manera: Corro el programa y la ventana se abre. Tengo un JPanel y un botón. Al presionar dicho botón, el JPanel debe de empezar a mostrar figuras una a una, de forma en la que cada una ,aparezca a un rango de tiempo, apreciada por el ojo humano. La cantidad de figuras que necesitan se encuentra dentro de la misma función que las muestra. Para aclarar mejor la parte de aparición de las figuras podemos tomar como ejemplo: se presiona el botón -> necesito 3 rombos, a cada 5segs aparece uno más y todo termina cuando el tercero se muestra en pantalla.

Comment: En ese caso la respuesta de @Alex podría servirte, poniendo atención a lo de los hijos (`Thread`)  y qué puede o no puede hacer el usuario mientras se crean todas las figuras. Si el usuario sólo debe mirar cómo se crean las figuras y nada más, entonces puedes poner un delay dentro del bucle y ya lo tienes.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que ocurre es que el for loop se ejecuta muy rápido y todo parece que se mostrarán todos los polígonos juntos.

Podrías hacer algo como esto:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    g.drawPolygon(poly[i]); //poligonos que quiero que vayan apareciendo
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

Pero esto no sería muy conveniente, porque Thread.sleep bloquea el thread en el que estás por ese tiempo, y la interface de usuario quedaría inaccesible hasta que se terminen de mostrar todos los polígonos.

Entonces tienes que hacer que los polígonos se muestren utilizando otro thread, o hilo.
Algo así:

```
        TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
            int i = 0;
            @Override
            public void run() {
                g.drawPolygon(poly[i++]);
                if (i >= 10) this.cancel();
            }
        };

        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, 1000);
```

El método Timer#scheduleAtFixedRate(), recibe un parámetro de tipo TimerTask, y ejecuta su método run() en un hilo separado, con un retardo inicial de 0 ms (2do parámetro), y lo repite cada 1000 ms (tercer parámetro).